# Loading a page into a dialog with ASP .Net Buttons doesnt fire button click event

Tags: jquery

I am loading a page into a jquery dialog.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $loading = $('<img src="../Images/loading.gif" alt="loading">');

        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').append($loading);
        var $link = $("#<%=lnkCustomise.ClientID %>").one('click', function() {
            $dialog.load($link.attr('href'))
                   .dialog({
                      title: $link.attr('title'),
                      width: 500,
                      height: 550
                    });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

The aspx page has 4 buttons.when I click on the buttons it shows me error.

Server Error in ‘/projectname’ Application.

The resource cannot be found.

I want to fire the server side click event of the buttons to perform some functionality.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it's readable!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for i guess

```
__doPostBack('<%= UniqueIdOfBtn %>', '');
```

Comment: Inside <script></script> tags